# How to group rows by frequency?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to know how many people putted `GRADE` 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 among the groups of people who made the evaluations 1 time, between 2 and 3 times, and more than 3 times. For instance, the group of people making the evaluations 1 time contains persons with ID `2` and `4`. In this group there are totally one evaluation `5`, and one evaluation `1`.

```
df =

ID_PERSON    EVALUATION_GRADE
1            2
1            2
1            3
1            5
2            5
3            2
3            5
3            1
4            1 
5            2
5            1
5            1
```

The result should be this one:

```
result =

FREQUENCY_GROUP   GRADE_1   GRADE_2   GRADE_3   GRADE_4   GRADE_5
"1 time"          1         0         0         0         1
"2-3 times"       3         2         0         0         1
"> 3 times"       0         2         1         0         1
```

If I do this `df.groupby(['EVALUATION_GRADE']).agg({'ID_PERSON': 'count'}).reset_index()`, then I get total number of persons that putted `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` and `5`. However how can I split them into frequency groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use first [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `size` first for find frequency, then [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) for create bins and last [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `size`, reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and fill missing columns by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df['FREQ'] = df.groupby('ID_PERSON')['EVALUATION_GRADE'].transform('size')
bins = [-np.inf, 1, 3, np.inf]
labels=['1 time','2-3 times','> 3 times']
df.FREQ = pd.cut(df.FREQ, bins=bins, labels=labels)

df = df.groupby(['FREQ', 'EVALUATION_GRADE'])['EVALUATION_GRADE'] \
       .size() \
       .unstack(fill_value=0) \
       .reindex(columns=np.arange(1,6), fill_value=0) 
df.columns = 'GRADE '  + df.columns.astype(str)
print (df)
           GRADE 1  GRADE 2  GRADE 3  GRADE 4  GRADE 5
FREQ                                                  
1 time           1        0        0        0        1
2-3 times        3        2        0        0        1
> 3 times        0        2        1        0        1
```

Comment: Just to understand. Would this `bins = [-np.inf, 1, 3, 5, np.inf]` mean this `labels=['1 time','2-3 times','4-5 times','> 5 times']` ?

Comment: Ya, I see problem instead -inf need `0`, sorry.

Comment: I cannot it test now, because I am only on phone.

Comment: And to your comment  - exactly, only use `bins = [0, 1, 3, 5, np.inf]`

Comment: nice usage of `cut` and `reindex`

Answer (score 1):

Well, basic idea could be as follows - use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) to get frequency groups and then [`pandas.crosstab.`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) to pivot data:

```
>>> def worker(x):
       if len(x) == 1:
           return "1 time" 
       elif len(x) <=3 :
           return "2-3 times"
       else:
           return "> 3 times"
>>> df['FREQUENCY_GROUP'] = df.groupby('ID_PERSON').transform(worker)
>>> df
    ID_PERSON  EVALUATION_GRADE FREQUENCY_GROUP
0           1                 2       > 3 times
1           1                 2       > 3 times
2           1                 3       > 3 times
3           1                 5       > 3 times
4           2                 5          1 time
5           3                 2       2-3 times
6           3                 5       2-3 times
7           3                 1       2-3 times
8           4                 1          1 time
9           5                 2       2-3 times
10          5                 1       2-3 times
11          5                 1       2-3 times
>>> pd.crosstab(df['FREQUENCY_GROUP'], 'GRADE ' + df['EVALUATION_GRADE'].astype('str'))
EVALUATION_GRADE  GRADE 1  GRADE 2  GRADE 3  GRADE 5
FREQUENCY_GROUP                                     
1 time                  1        0        0        1
2-3 times               3        2        0        1
> 3 times               0        2        1        1
```

Comment: I don't understand how do you obtain `> 3 times`, `1 time` and `2-3 times`.

Comment: @user7379562 sorry forgot to add the function there

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer that should generalize to any number of grades or ids

```
d = {1: '1 time', 2:'2-3 times', 3:'2-3 times', 4:'> 3 times'} 

df['FREQUENCY_GROUP'] = df.groupby('ID_PERSON')['ID_PERSON']\
                          .transform('size')\
                          .clip_upper(4)\
                          .map(d)

df1 = df.pivot_table(index='FREQUENCY_GROUP', 
                     columns='EVALUATION_GRADE', 
                     values='ID_PERSON', 
                     aggfunc='count', 
                     fill_value=0)\
       .reindex(columns=range(df.EVALUATION_GRADE.min(), 
                              df.EVALUATION_GRADE.max() + 1), 
                fill_value=0)

df1.columns = 'GRADE_'  + df1.columns.astype(str)
```

## output

```
                 GRADE_1  GRADE_2  GRADE_3  GRADE_4  GRADE_5
FREQUENCY_GROUP                                             
1 time                 1        0        0        0        1
2-3 times              3        2        0        0        1
> 3 times              0        2        1        0        1
```